# Pyspark python reduceByKey filter by math.max

Tags: python, apache-spark, filter, pyspark

I have a rdd with Key as date and Value as . something like:

```
2017-07-03 00:00:00 (u'LANXESS', 17119)
2017-07-03 00:00:00 (u'SCHALTBAU', 225)
2018-05-08 00:00:00 (u'LINDE', 8105)
2018-05-08 00:00:00 (u'HSBC', 16084)
```

I want to use rdd.reduceByKey and I want to choose the maximum of the "somenumber".

so for the sample input I am expecting to see:

```
2017-07-03 00:00:00 (u'LANXESS', 17119)
2018-05-08 00:00:00 (u'HSBC', 16084)
```

which is actually the date is my key and the values are got filtered.

I am trying to do something like:

```
test4 = test3.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: math.max(a_2))
```

but I assume its wrong.

How would I be able to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can user python builtin max function with key argument. Max function compare items by key function (lambda x: x[1] or itemgetter(1) in your case).

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([
    ('2017-07-03 00:00:00', (u'LANXESS', 17119)),
    ('2017-07-03 00:00:00', (u'SCHALTBAU', 225)),
    ('2018-05-08 00:00:00', (u'LINDE', 8105)),
    ('2018-05-08 00:00:00', (u'HSBC', 16084)),
]).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: max((x, y), key=lambda x: x[1]))
rdd.collect()
```

or with more functional way

```
from operator import itemgetter
from functools import partial

reduce_func = partial(max, key=itemgetter(1))
rdd = sc.parallelize([
    ('2017-07-03 00:00:00', (u'LANXESS', 17119)),
    ('2017-07-03 00:00:00', (u'SCHALTBAU', 225)),
    ('2018-05-08 00:00:00', (u'LINDE', 8105)),
    ('2018-05-08 00:00:00', (u'HSBC', 16084)),
]).reduceByKey(reduce_func)
rdd.collect()
```

Results:

```
[('2018-05-08 00:00:00', ('HSBC', 16084)),
 ('2017-07-03 00:00:00', ('LANXESS', 17119))]
```